# Haschildnodes() does not work

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a tree view and a delete button on the webpage. The tree view loads with parent nodes and child nodes. If I click on delete after selecting a parent node with child nodes, it should give me a message provided below accordingly with a confirmation box.

Right now, when I select a parent node without any child nodes it gives me the following message: ""The element has at least one child.".
When it should be giving me this message: "The element has no children."

Code:

```
function check() {
    var treeViewData = window["<%=nav_tree_items.ClientID%>" + "_Data"];
    var selectedNode = document.getElementById(treeViewData.selectedNodeID.value);

    var hasChilds = selectedNode.hasChildNodes();

    if (hasChilds) {
        alert("The element has at least one child.");
    } else {
        alert("The element has no children.");
    }
```

Please help.
Thank you and sorry if I may have caused confusion in my explanation

Comment: What makes you sure the element has no child nodes *of any type*?  Remember that a stray newline in the HTML source can result in a text node being included in the DOM.

Comment: I'd inspect the `nodeType` for each child. There's probably something there you didn't expect: http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-DOM-Level-1/level-one-core.html#ID-1950641247

Comment: How do I know which nodetype? IS there any way of checking that?

Answer (score 4):

Try checking

```
var hasChilds = selectedNode.children.length > 0;
```

This will check for elements instead of `childNodes` which will check for elements and text nodes, which can come from whitespace in your markup.

Comment: Tried the above. But it alerts there are no children when there are.