# javascript checking for child element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Just doing a simple check for a child within my div with an id. But it always returns true regardless if its empty or not. Whats going on?

```html
<html>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1 id="number"></h1>
<div id="bigbox">
   <p>Follow us:</p>
   <div id="box">
     <!-- javascript is lying about this div -->    
   </div>
   
</div>
<input id="input" type="button" value="click" />



<script>
$("#input").click(function(){
    var ele = document.getElementById('box');
    if (ele.hasChildNodes()) {
        alert("has");
        alert(ele.hasChildNodes());
    }
    else{
        alert("not");
        alert(ele.hasChildNodes());
    }
}); 
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: The hasChildNodes() method returns true if the specified node has any child nodes, otherwise false.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Haschildnodes() does not work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8565928/haschildnodes-does-not-work)

Comment: @divy3993 What child node am I missing? The div with id=box has no children. Are you counting the comment? I removed that and it still returns true. I've been experimenting with it and it always says true regardless of what i've done to it.

Comment: Spaces and line-feeds are text nodes, so it has children.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try like this

```
if ( $('#box').children().length > 0 ) {
     // this div has child and do something
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually i think everything is perfect, but there are White spaces in your div box, so remove the space and try, would solve your problem.

The hasChildNodes() method returns true if the specified node has any child nodes, otherwise false.

> Note: Whitespace inside a node is considered as text nodes, so if you
>   leave any white space or line feeds inside an element, that element
>   still has child nodes.

```
<div id="box"></div> <!-- No space here between start and end -->
```

**CHECK THIS** [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/822g5jx7/)

Answer (score 1):

Spaces and line-feeds are text nodes, so it has children. If you don't want to use jQuery, you can simply use:

```
ele = document.getElementById('box');
if (ele.children.length > 0)) {
    alert("has");
    alert(ele.hasChildNodes());
}
else{
    alert("not");
    alert(ele.hasChildNodes());
}
```